# How to develop Raw Keyed State for apache flink?

Tags: stream, streaming, apache-flink, stateful

I need to implement bloom filter as state for Apache Flink, I used `ValueState` for it which contain an instance of bloom filter and each time I update the value of state.

```
state = getRuntimeContext.getState(
      new ValueStateDescriptor[BloomFilter](
         "value-bloomfilter", 
         createTypeInformation[BloomFilter]
      )
)
```

But I need more efficient way such as customized state for it. Unfortunately I couldn't find any resource about how to develop raw state for Apache Flink.

Comment: Could you add some details about how you plan to use it? Do you need an operator-state or a keyed-state? Your example indicates that you might need a keyed state. Is that right?

Comment: @TobiSH yes, I need Keyed state as I mentioned on question title.
I just need an example of how to develop raw state, operator or keyed doesn't matter right know for me.

Comment: Sorry missed that it is already written at your title. Do you have a concrete problem or are you just running some experiments? Why not using e.g. the `ValueState`? Performance issues?

Comment: @TobiSH I want to make a benchmark between them.